# How to replace when there's a multimatch in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I don't know if this is properly expressed but here's the example:

I got a few hundred lines like this ones:

```
word1.word2.word3.1.09
word1.word2.2.14
word1.word2.word3.word4.3.22
word1.1.09
```

and I want to convert those to:

```
word1 word2 word3 1.09
word1 word2 2.14
word1 word2 word3 word4 3.22
word1 1.09
```

So far I reached this point that matches those:

```
(([a-z0-9]+).+)([0-9]+.[0-9]+)
```

And usually I would space the $1 $2 $3, but in this case the $1 matches multiple times the first alphanumeric text. Can I do this just with regex or I got to process the $1 afterwards with another language?.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you showed more realistic data. For example, I'm assuming that the `wordx` don't really all end with a digit, right? Or do they?

Comment: And what flavor of regex are you using?

Comment: This is for renaming a pack of files with that structure, the words doesn't have to be like "wordX" or "wordX" X being a number. It could be like a random mix of letters and numbers, like maybe an acronym.
Another example will be this one  --------------> new.fc2systems.2.09   ------becomes--------> new fc2systems 2.09   --------------> ( it comes from the full name: new file cleaner for 2 systems 2.09 )

Comment: And the flavor, no idea, I'm using regexpal ( javascript ) to test it, and Name Twister ( http://12noon.com/?page_id=121 ) for the renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the (presumably invented) sample input you gave, this will work:

```
\.(?!\d{2}$)  # search string

" "           # replace string: a single space
```

i.e., this looks for the periods you want to strip out, and replaces them with a space.

Explained:

```
\.     # look for a period, but ignore it if the negative lookahead matches:
(?!    # open negative lookahead
\d{2}$ # look for exactly two digits, at the end of the string
)      # close lookahead
```

Comment: You may also want the negative look ahead to be: \d+[.]\d{2} that way if your amount is 12.23 it will still kill the dot in front of the 12

Comment: @JoshMiller. What you posted doesn't work. I think what you mean is I may want `(?<!\d{2})\.(?!\d{2}$)` with a negative lookbehind for two digits. That's possible, and would work, but I thought I would wait for feedback from the OP before spending more time mind-reading about what the real input looks like :-)

Comment: This one will replace ALL periods for a space, in the example it has to replace all periods but the period for the last part, it's a version number.

Comment: @Fabman. No, it doesn't. The negative lookahead prevents it from replacing the period in the version number at the end. Try it and see if it works.

Comment: Ah! sorry!, I gonna try, my knowledge of regex it's kind of limited so far, that's what it looked it was going to do.

Comment: OK. Name Twister uses .NET regular expressions. I'm not sure they support lookahead. So this answer may or may not work. You'll just have to try it.

Comment: Sorry to be a PITA but it seems that regex doesn't work on http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html, that's what I'm using to test the replacement. ( I'll test it in Name Twister when I come back home ).